# Dictionary<string, bool?> error - Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting **System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.** error in my following code.

```
//temporary var for storing column sort orders according to view type
        Dictionary<string, bool?> tempColumnSortOrders=new Dictionary<string,bool?>(4);
 //Check for column name in col list
        if (tempColumnSortOrders.ContainsKey(fieldToSort))
        {
            //If exists set column sort order to new sort order
            //Set new sort order
            tempColumnSortOrders[fieldToSort] = sortOrder;
            var tempSortOrders = tempColumnSortOrders;
            //remove sort order of other columns
            foreach (var kvp in tempSortOrders)
            {
                //Reset other columns sort other than current column sort
                if (kvp.Key != fieldToSort)
                {
                    tempSortOrders[kvp.Key] = null;
                }
            }
            //Return name of column to sort
            return fieldToSort;
        }
```

**Stack Trace**

> *[InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.]
>
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
>   resource) +52    System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNext() +44 
>   GlaziersCenter.Handlers.GetSiteViews.getColumnToSort(Int32 viewType)
>   in
>   d:\Projects\GlaziersCenter\GlaziersCenter\Handlers\GetSiteViews.ashx.cs:184
>   GlaziersCenter.Handlers.GetSiteViews.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) in
>   d:\Projects\GlaziersCenter\GlaziersCenter\Handlers\GetSiteViews.ashx.cs:68
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +341    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69*

Comment: You can't edit the collection used in the foreach in the foreach.

Comment: Use for loop or try my solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code instead,

```
List<string> keys = new List<string>(tempSortOrders.Keys);
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    //Reset other columns sort other than current column sort
    if (key != fieldToSort)
    {
        tempSortOrders[key] = null;
    }
}
```

**Update,**

Converting the collection to list will be solve the issue.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: have you tried this? please try before say not working.

Comment: This will result in the same Exception. The underlying collection is still being modified, even though you're only enumerating the keys.

Comment: This works, but creates a whole new `List< >` just to enumerate the keys, which is very inefficient.

Comment: @Rik: it is just creating whole new `List<>` with only keys. It doesn't duplicate the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

`foreach` loop doesn't allow mutations of the collection you iterate on. To change a collection, use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because in this loop, you have modified your dictionary tempSortOrders..

```
foreach (var kvp in tempSortOrders)
        {
            //Reset other columns sort other than current column sort
            if (kvp.Key != fieldToSort)
            {
                tempSortOrders[kvp.Key] = null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are modifying the for each collection

foreach (var kvp in **tempSortOrders**)

**tempSortOrders**[kvp.Key] = null;

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating a collection and modifying the same is not supported in `Dictionary` If you want to do that you can use `ConcurrentDictionary` which will be a overkill for this, since you're using single thread.

Try this.

```
foreach (var kvp in tempSortOrders.ToArray())<--Note ToArray here
{
    //Reset other columns sort other than current column sort
    if (kvp.Key != fieldToSort)
    {
        tempSortOrders[kvp.Key] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal Yes Dictionary.ToArray, What's wrong with that?

Comment: You will duplicate the entire dictionary. better to use `Keys.ToArray`

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a collection in a while it's being enumerated in a `foreach` loop. this is because it could lead to some unexpected behavior.

Use a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: Property or indexer 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,bool?>.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only - I tried this already.

Comment: readonly .. I guess you'll have to use a regular `for` loop, then.